# Does using system-wide OpenVPN (occasionally) on my workmachine compromise my security or anonymity?

Tags: internet, security, vpn, openvpn

So, I want to use OpenVPN on my main installation (16.04) but if I do it only occasionally and leave the connection unencrypted during normal usage,

1. Will my anonymity be compromised online?
2. Can it have any negative impact on netbanking and such, while on normal usage? (I never ever do that while on VPN)

Also, if I make a separate user account for OpenVPN, will this improve the situation?

I'm half a mind to install a separate OS for OpenVPN alone, and keep it on a pendrive or something like that, but that seems to be overkill (and unnecessarily complicated).

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The basic thing you need to understand about VPNs is that it is routing your internet connection through the place your VPN is connected to. Like if I am using a VPN from my office configured to connect to my home connection, my internet connection is being routed through my home. So the information I upload is first sent to my home and then uploaded and vice-versa for downloads. While this information is transferred between my home and office, it is encrypted by the VPN protocol you are using.

Since you have mentioned that you are trying to protect your anonymity online, I am assuming that you are using openVPN to connect to an unknown VPN not owned by you. If this is the case, and if the VPN you are connecting to is keeping logs, then both your anonymity and your banking details are not secure. All someone need to do is access those logs and they can get you IP and you banking details. Keeping the OS on a pendrive is not going to affect this.

If anonymity is your main goal, I would suggest using tor. You do not need to worry about the logs the exit node might be keeping since your connection is bounced about multiple times before it reaches the exit node.

And netbanking through a VPN you do not own is a bad idea as you must have already realised.

You can do what I do. Use a VPN for streaming videos, and tor for everything else. For netbanking, turn everything off and use your regular connection.